# right syntax to use near 'TOKUDB_DEFAULT'

Tags: mysql, percona

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE stable1 ( column_a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, column_b INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=TokuDB, ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_DEFAULT;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TOKUDB_DEFAULT' at line 1

CREATE TABLE stable1 ( column_a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, column_b INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=TokuDB ROW_FORMAT=tokudb_zlib;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tokudb_zlib' at line 1
```

it is on Percona Server 8.0

why??

Comment: *near 'tokudb_zlib' at line 1* - format is not (properly) registered. Follow engine installation/registration instructions with accuracy. And check pre-requisites for zlib compression use.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the changes in this JIRA link: https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-4942

To use a specific row_format or tokudb_row_format do the following instead:

```
SET SESSION tokudb_row_format=TOKUDB_LZMA;
CREATE TABLE stable1 ( column_a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, column_b INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=TokuDB;
```

To check what compression method is used by the table you can run this command from the shell:

```
tokuftdump --header <tablename>_main*.tokudb
```